# Why do we need semaphores on single cpu?

Tags: semaphore

I have read that we use semaphores inside the linux kerenl,and i have read that semaphores has advantages even in one single cpu (we can run only one process\thread). Can anyone please give me an example of a problem that semaphore solves(inside the kernel)?

In my view, there can be a problem only if we have more than one cpu, because two process may call system calls that use the same data structure, and probablly cause problems.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You seem to have the idea that semaphores' uses are limited to mutual exclusion.  That is not the case -- in fact, some of their uses don't involve strict mutual exclusion at all.  Semaphores serve a variety of inter-process / inter-thread coordination purposes that mutexes cannot, and that aren't necessarily related to true concurrency.

Comment: And none of these synchronization objects are new ideas.  They've been around, and useful, since long before it was common for computers to have multiple cores.

Comment: @JohnBollinger as far as i understand from this link
http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-semaphores-in-linux.html
"Semaphore as used in an operating system to restrict the access to resources by multiple processes at the same time"
if i have process1 which running how can another porcess access the same resource?

Comment: Common example are : Barrier (waiting threads to be at same level of code), Producer - Consumer pattern, Writter- Reader pattern.

Comment: @SamiTahri i am not sure i am understantind your examples, can you please provide more details? and how do we use semaphores in your example? thanks!

Comment: @MosheLevy, semaphores are most fundamentally about constraining *order of operations* across multiple threads of execution.  Restricting access to resources is just one application of such constraints, albeit a very important one.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need more than one CPU for concurrency. The multiple CPUs are really "an implementation detail," a piece of hardware quirkiness that you can abstract away from. Concurrency is a logical property of programs. You can have concurrency without multiple CPUs, and use multiple CPUs without "real concurrency".

Consider a web server. It *has* to be "concurrent," in the sense that it *must* serve multiple clients at once, hold information about multiple connections and once, and process multiple requests at once. You can have it literally do this, by having multiple CPUs all working at the same time. Yet, the program only has to *appear* to do multiple things at once. It could just as well be running on one CPU and context switching to fairly service all the work put to it. The fact that a web-server does multiple things at once is part of its interface: the I/O for the connections are interleaved, if a request has exclusively locked a resource, another request won't start trying to manipulate that same resource, etc. Writing a web server without concurrency produces a program that is wrong.

Semaphores help you with concurrency, by letting you control the way processes access resources. You asked, if you had one process running, how another could run at the same time with only a single core. Well, as I said, concurrency doesn't *need* multiple cores. The first process can be paused, and the second one started while the first one is still unfinished. This is just an implementation detail; logically, to the program writer, the two processes are running simultaneously, whether there are multiple cores or not. If the program was written without semaphores (or had broken concurrency in some other way), it would be wrong, even on a single core. Physically, this will be because context switching can abruptly pause one computation and start another at any time, and, without semaphores, the newly live thread won't know what resources it can and cannot access. Logically, this will be because the processes *are* running simultaneously, once you abstract yourself away from the implementation, and, in general, processes running simultaneously can walk over each other if not properly synchronized.

For an example applicable to an OS kernel, consider that every process is logically running concurrently with every other process. A kernel provides the implementation that makes this concurrency work. A resource that two processes may want simultaneously is a hard drive. A semaphore might be used in the kernel to track whether a given drive is currently busy with a read or write. A process trying to read or write to the same disk will ask the kernel to do so, and the kernel can check the semaphore to see that the disk is still busy and force the offending process to wait. Now, an operating system *does* count as low level code, so in some places, yes, you might want to omit some otherwise vital concurrency safeguards when running on a single CPU, because your *job* is to handle such implementation details, but higher level parts may still use them.

In contrast, consider a number-crunching program. Let's say it's processing each element of a huge array of data into an equal-sized array of modified data (a functional `map` operation). It can use multiple CPUs to do this more quickly, but it can also work one CPU. The observable behavior of the program is the same, and you never get any idea that it's doing multiple things at once from its behavior. Numbers go in, numbers come out, who cares what happens in the middle? Writing such a program without the ability to do multiple things at once does not produce a logically incorrect program, just a slow one. Such a program probably does not need semaphores when running on a single CPU, because it didn't need concurrency in the first place.

Comment: To make sure i understand(the exanple with the kerenl), let's say a process A wants to read from the disc, then it has to use some system call which read's from the disc, i assume reading from the disc is blocking system call so process A going to sleep.
Now process B is running, it wants to write to the disc, so it uses some system call, but we cant let it write to the disc before process A is finished. Hence, we use the semaphore to avoid occasions like this one?